# WCF-project will not return data with 64-bit Win Vista and VS2010

Tags: wcf, linq, 64-bit, windows-vista

I thought I found the solution to my problem when I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/22a7474c-b54d-4be0-928b-acc8b0a5a091/), but it didn't work for me.

When I run in debug mode, my `WcfTestClient` does not retrieve any data and I receive the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b50) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7040] WCFTestClient.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).....................................
```

What WILL retrieve data is the following method:

```
public List<WShortDeal> Test()
    {
        try
        {
            return entities.ProductInstance_Deal
                .Select(d => new WShortDeal()
                {
                    Id = d.Deal.Id
                   // ,
                   // Name = d.Deal.Deal_Language.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Language.Id == 1).Name**
                    ,
                    NewPrice = (double)d.ProductInstance.Price * (1 - d.Deal.SalesPercentage / 100)
                    ,
                    OldPrice = (double)d.ProductInstance.Price
                    ,
                    Valuta = d.ProductInstance.Valuta.ValutaCode
                    ,
                    Type = d.Deal.Type
                    ,
                    IdCompanyAccount = d.ProductInstance.IdCompanyAccount
                })
                    .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If I uncomment the two lines that are now commented out, though, I stop receiving data and receive the error message mentioned above in my output window.

Also if I add this line

```
  ,ProductCategory = d.ProductInstance.ProductType.ProductCategory.ProductCategory_Language.Where(pcl => pcl.IdLanguage == idLanguage).Single().Name
```

instead of the line

```
 , Name = d.Deal.Deal_Language.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Language.Id == 1).Name
```

to my original SELECT-statement, it will also return no data. So I guess maybe it has something to do with all the tables that represent the many-to-many-relationship with my Language-table(??). Because whenever I forget about the join with the "ProductCategory_Language"-table, I can retrieve data again.

Could someone please help? Is there another solution for my problem? I've been struggling with this problem for days now :(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the looks of it it does not seem a WCF issue. 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll ... this MIGHT indicate a problem in your data model. Is your model in sync with your Database?
Also try to refactor the Deal_Language selection part into a seperate utility method. This way it will help you to debug better.

Comment: @ CSharpenter Thanks for the reaction; I will give it a try...........I HAVE been struggling with getting my model in sync, that IS true! I will let u know. Q: how do I "refactor the Deal_Language selection part into a seperate utility method"?

Comment: private string ExtractLanguageName(DealEntityType deal, int langID) // replace DealEntityType with the real type of Deal 
{ var deal_Lang = deal.Deal_Language.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Language.Id == langID); if (deal_Lang != null) { return deal_Lang.Name; } return string.Empty; // or throw exception, or other action }

Comment: // Name = ExtractLanguageName(d.Deal, 1);
        // instead of 
        // Name = d.Deal.Deal_Language.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Language.Id == 1).Name**

Comment: @CSharpenter THANKS AGAIN! I've tried it...Still NO luck :(  I have discovered something new though. See the edit of my original question above

Comment: I also have to mention: when running query in LinqPad, I WILL get data!

Answer (score 0):

What if the line returns a null before selecting the name?
Try

```
  Name = d.Deal.Deal_Language.Where(l => l.Language.Id == 1)
         .Select(s=>s.Name).SingleOrDefault()
```